# 10.7.4 changed my dock background—how do I change it back?

Tags: macos, dock

I upgraded to 10.7.4 and my dock on the bottom (with no enhancements) received this light/shadow box effect on startup. (It used to have no background.) I don't seen an option to remove it—is this a bug or a permanent change, and how can I easily revert it?

[image: shadow]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

1. Launch Terminal.app from /Applications/Utilities/
2. Type `defaults write com.apple.dock no-glass -boolean NO` and press return.
3. Type `killall Dock` and press return.